# Does anybody know of a good all-in-one install to get django up and running on OS X

Tags: django, macos

i.e. something that would install django + mySQL + python-mysql in one package

hoping to make it easy for a friend to get up and running

Comment: Simple answer is that there's not really a good one-click Django install. @Guard's answer is as good as you're going to get. However, it's worth noting that if deploying Django is too difficult a task, using Django in the first place should be questioned.

Comment: I suggest you search for the many, many questions on StackOverflow regarding problems with getting this exact combination to work, i.e. Python, MySQLdb, MySQL client libraries.  Django is easy once you get the rest going.  By far the easiest and most reliable way is to use a complete solution from one of the big three open source pacakage managers for OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the beginner I recommend:

1) MAMP for MySQL + phpMyAdmin

2) Python is pre-installed

3)

```
easy_install pip
```

4) (yes, do it manually, it makes sense)

```
pip install mysql-python django
```

Comment: I hope the beginner is successful with this.  But I think it is doing a disservice to recommend unsustainable practices.  Sooner or later, you will need to upgrade one or more components and, without a comprehensive package manager (like the ones I've mentioned), you'll likely run into problems and spend a lot of time trying to remember what you did in the first place and trying to get everything working after Apple changes something in OS X. Plus getting familiar with a package manager will pay off with other projects as well.

Comment: @NedDeily, I agree, and personally I use MacPorts (though I prefer MAMP for Apache and MySQL, though I use them quite seldom on the working machine). But the question was specific to the guy who want to start ASAP (at least as I understood it), and mumbling with multiple CLI commands is not the best way for python starter to feel the spirit %)

Comment: I agree trying to keep it as simple as possible is a good goal, but, if you add up the number of actions that need to be taken to get going for either scenario, I doubt there is a significant difference.  And you're going to have to use a CLI in either case.

Answer (score 2):

Use a third-party open source package manager.  It can be very difficult to pick and choose components from different sources and get them all to work together.  The major package managers available for OS X are `Homebrew`, `MacPorts`, and `Fink`.  I prefer `MacPorts`.  Follow [the instructions here](http://www.macports.org/install.php) to download and install the MacPorts base package.  Then make sure your [shell path includes](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.shell.postflight) `/opt/local/bin`.  Then type:

```
sudo port install py27-django py27-mysql
```

That will install compatible versions of Python, MySQL client libraries, the Python MySQL database adapter, and Django *and* will allow you to easily keep everything up-to-date as well.

Comment: I was typing something like this, but for [`brew`](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/).

Answer (score 0):

Install [PIP](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (it will be useful in the future for every python or django package you'll need while developing your project.)

Then, open terminal and write `pip install Django`. Pip will install django on your machine, solving all dependencies.

Then, after installing mySQL, you can use pip for installing python-mysql.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but that doesn't install mysql or mysql-python

Comment: at first, i didn't seen the mysql part in your question... fixing right now ;) But for installing everything python related, I can assure you that there is nothing as good as PIP.

Comment: (before beginning a brand new django installation, I would recommend you give a try to virtualenv too http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv ... It will help you a lot in the future)